# Why Pinterest Profile Widget is not showing in jQuery UI Tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, pinterest

I need to show pinterest profile widget to show in jQuery UI Tabs. But some how its not working and I had banging my head from few hours but did not find a solution so far.

My HTML Looks like:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>first tab</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
              <p>second tab</p>
    <a data-pin-do="embedUser" href="http://pinterest.com/ruralwomennz/"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>third tab</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Please refer to this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4pAqv/9/)

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This may be happening because the tab that the widget is placed in is not displayed (computed by the browser) by default, therefore the widget's techniques to build itself fail. There may be a script which works with height/width and if the element and its parent are set to `display: none`, the reference fails.